# Zoom an image with mouseover on image in another div

Tags: jquery

There is many plugins for zooming image (like [jqzoom](http://www.mind-projects.it/projects/jqzoom/index.php)). But I want to zoom image with hovering on image in another div:
[image]

Is there any way to have an effect like jqzoom (inner zoom)but with mouseover on another element?
I want this effect : seavello.com/r/zoom/zoom.html, but with mouseover on thumbnial not main image
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If the href is url for big image then:

```
var big = $('.main img');
$('.tumb').mouseover(function() {
   big.attr('src', $(this).attr('href'));
}).mouseout(function() {
   big.attr('src', '');
});
```

you can also preload images on start.

```
var images = $.map($('.tumb'), function(item, index) {
   var img = new Image();
   img.src = item.attr('href');
   return img;
});
```

You can also add animations on hover.

Comment: thanks for your help. But I want this effect : http://seavello.com/r/zoom/zoom.html, but with mouseover on thumbnal not main image

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('img').hover(
        function () { 
            $(this).animate({width: '+=10', height: '+=10'}, 500);
        },
        function () {
            $(this).animate({width: '-=10', height: '-=10'}, 500);
    });
});
```